# I can see that nvm and npm is not installed after succesfull installation

Tags: npm, nvm

I am installing nvm and npm like this:

```
  curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash

  echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> /home/deployer/.profile
  source /home/deployer/.profile
  # source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  nvm install v0.12.9
  nvm use v0.12.9
  nvm alias default v0.12.9

  curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

with bash and clearly see a successfull installation ("It worked" prompt), but after it stops and I type nvm or npm in the console I get:

No command 'nvm' found, did you mean:
The program 'npm' is currently not installed.

If I write this in the console:

source /home/deployer/.profile

nvm starts working, but why I need to repeat this process, not sure.

Comment: Tell me what is it saying if you try `which nvm` and `which npm` in terminal.

Comment: brings nothing, if I write in the console source /home/deployer/.profile which nvm still brings nothing, which npm brings /root/.nvm/v0.12.9/bin/npm

Comment: Can you check your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.zshrc` file if there are any lines added for nvm.

Comment: I am adding myself  echo "[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> /home/deployer/.profile

Comment: Did it work? If you havent it would be helpful if you checked out this guide: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

Comment: It is better if you add it in .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that your shell is not sourcing `.profile` for you. Perhaps you're using a non-login shell; perhaps your OS sources a different file when logging in.

What happens if you add `. $HOME/.profile` to your `.bashrc`, for example?